# SQL for Alphabetically sorting a string of categories with a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I wonder if someone could help me with the SQL to alphabetically order  a `Category` column.

Let me explain: I have inherited a database for cataloguing all my books. Within the database I have a table called `BOOKS`.

The `BOOKS` table contains many columns, but the one I am trying to re-order is called `Categories`.

Within this table, each new line (starting with LINEID=1) contains the name of a book I hold within my book collection; plus all the details I need about the book etc. There are 500+ lines (more than 500 ROWID's) at the moment. I need to sort each LINEID and not the whole Table by this column.

Each new line within the `Categories` column is of datatype `TEXT` which can hold multiple text entries between square brackets (I did not design it this way). However if I am entering the details of a new books I can add as many user defined 'categories' as I want per book as long as they are between double quotes separated by a comma. For example:

```
[ "Books - Hardback","Books - Read","Books - WWII","John Kenneally","Leslie Jackson","Irish Guards","Anzio","The Tunisian Campaign","Italy","Autobiography","Books - War","Desertion","Lee Enfield" ]
[ "Books - Hardback","Books - Read","Books - WWII","Airman","RAF","USAF","Burma","C47 Dakota","Flying Tigers","Indo-China","Lee Crane","P40 Tomahawk","Pilots","Robert Ryan" ]
```

As you can see each "double bracketed", entry is not in order alphabetically. I would like the SQL query to separate each `,` `""`, alphabetically by the first letter of the word or first word where there are more than one. I can manually add or amend the categories as I need to. But the majority of the 500+ lines are not presently in Alphabetical order, which is my preference.

The following query doesn't throw an error but it doesn't Order the entries.

```
SELECT Categories
FROM BOOK
ORDER BY substr(Categories, instr(Categories, ',"') + 2, instr(Categories || ',"', '","') - instr(Categories, ',"') - 2) ASC;
```

I wonder if anyone can advise a better way using standard SQL. I am presently using SQLite version 3.4.4. now that I have retired.

Thank you in advance.

Fanflame

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly what you need, but I stored the two records of your example with an ID in table I called books. Then I tried a query like this

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(id, categories, str) AS (
    SELECT id, '', categories||',' FROM books
    UNION ALL SELECT
    id,
    substr(str, 0, instr(str, ',')),
    substr(str, instr(str, ',')+1)
    FROM split WHERE str!=''
) 
,tab as (SELECT id, rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(categories,'[',''),']',''))) as categories
FROM split
WHERE categories!='')

SELECT id,'['||group_concat(categories)||']' as categories
FROM (select * from tab order by categories asc)
GROUP BY id
```

where the first cte splits column categories in many lines; each values of the "new" categories is one of the strings between "".
The second cte is just replacing some characters that can give problems when ordering (spaces and brackets in this case).
Finally I use the group_concat function grouping by id to obtain two rows with the column categories containing values orbere alphabetically. I'm not sure the order by in the subquery is the best solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: Many thanks for this Gulfus, I'm on my mobile at the moment so will look at this more intently when home tomorrow morning 

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance Gufus,
I didn't get to look at this until this afternoon and was interested as I had tried RECURSIVE at first but couldn't get it working. I copied your code and ran that on the full test database and even though it ran it showed the following:
[15:59:09] SQLiteStudio was unable to extract metadata from the query. Results won't be editable.

Comment: Having played around with this it appears to be woring in a sql command line environment, but the error reoccurs in the SQLiteStudio.3.4.4 suite. It has also been reported as a bug to sqlite support...